# Como ultilizar Switch y Case en calculo de Areas en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo que hacer un codigo que me permita calcular varias areas en el mismo programa ( Triangulo, Cuadrado, Rectangulo y Circunferencia ) Ya tengo la idea de como hacer los codigos individuales, pero no se como hacer que pase de un codigo a otro, segun mi profesor dijo se ultiliza Switch y Case pero no se donde implementarlos.

Aca un Breve ejemplo del codigo con solo 2 poligonos:

```
switch (Area){

          case 1: double area = 0, b = 0, h = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Encontrar el Area de un Rectangulo.");
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la Base de rectangulo");
        b = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la altura del Rectangulo");
        h = Int32.ParseI(Console.ReadLine());
        Area = b * h; 
        Console.WriteLine("El Area del Rectangulo: " + area); break;

        case 2: double Area = 0, b = 0, h = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Encontra el Area de un Triangulo");
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la base del Triangulo");
        b = Int32.Parse(ConsoleReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la Altura del Triangulo");
        h = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        area = (b * h) / 2;
        Console.WriteLine("El Area del Triangulo" + area); break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrias usar el `while` para permanencer en un loop que pida si quiere continuar o salir.
Mientras que el `switch` lo usas para que ingrese la opcion del area que quiera ejecutar.

Algo com esto:

```
public static void Main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese codigo area calcular:");
        int TipoArea = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (TipoArea)
        {
            case 1: 
                AreaReactangulo();
                break;
            case 2: 
                AreaTriangulo();
                break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Desea Calcular otra arear ? Y/N");
        string respuesta = Console.ReadLine();

        if(respuesta != "Y")
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}


private static void AreaReactangulo()
{
    double area = 0, b = 0, h = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Encontrar el Area de un Rectangulo.");
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la Base de rectangulo");
    b = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la altura del Rectangulo");
    h = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Area = b * h; 
    Console.WriteLine("El Area del Rectangulo: " + area); break;
}

private static void  AreaTriangulo()
{
    double Area = 0, b = 0, h = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Encontra el Area de un Triangulo");
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la base del Triangulo");
    b = Int32.Parse(ConsoleReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la Altura del Triangulo");
    h = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    area = (b * h) / 2;
    Console.WriteLine("El Area del Triangulo" + area); break;
}
```

Si usas funciones es mejor asi queda mas prolijo el codigo

Answer (score 1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cada una de las clases que heredan de polígono, en el constructor, van los datos necesario para realizar el cálculo del Area(). En el triángulo por ejemplo la base y la altura.
Luego se puede hacer el switch-case para el menú y crear una nueva instancia de la figura elegida.

```
  Poligono p1;
  switch (TipoDePoligono)
    {
        case 1:
            //Área del triángulo
            p1 = new Triangulo(basePedida,halturaPedida);
            break;
        case 2: 
            //Área del cuadrado
            p1 = new Cuadrado(LadoPedido);
            break;
    }
    if(p1!=null){
       Console.Writeline("El área es: "+p1.Area());
    }
```